# Typescript Argument of type 'MyType<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<MyType<T>>'

Tags: typescript, vim, tsc, typescript-partial

I am using [Quramy/tsuquyomi](https://github.com/Quramy/tsuquyomi) plugin for VIM and I am getting this error:

```
Argument of type 'MyType<T>' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Partial<MyType<T>>'
```

`tsc` is compiling with no issue. This error is present only in VIM.

I've tried also another plugin for TSServer [leafgarland/typescript-vim'](https://github.com/leafgarland/typescript-vim) but I have the same error.

`MyType` is quite complex, but shouldn't it be always possible to use a `MyType` as paramter of type `Partial<MyType>`?

Comment: Please share your code

Comment: Vim has nothing to do with this: use the plugin's issue tracker.